# Course or book - Math Foundations in CS

Tags: computer-science, education, book-recommendation

I want to improve my math skills, now I'm trying to find good route for this purpose. I'm using Khan Academy, and recently found "CS103 - Mathematical Foundations of Computing" course which looks good but pretty expensive for me.

Is some book or not expensive/free course available which gives a good foundation in math for future usage in different fields such as statistics, algorithms, data analysis, machine learning etc?

Comment: A lot to ask for free. You might find something at MIT open courseware. Google it and see what's on offer. MIT puts some of their college courses on the website with book recommentdations, supplementary materials and so on. The maths department alone has a fairly long list. No doubt the CS folk have outdone them. If you email them they might even make  some suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking for a book on Math Foundations in CS, it is my opinion that such a book would emphasize logic, set theory, counting principles, functions and relations, and other discrete structures such as lattices and (especially) finite state machines. The analysis of algorithms would probably come next in this list, but certainly not statistics, data analysis, or machine learning as "foundations" topics.

Personally, I think *Book of Proof* by Hammack or *How to Prove It: A Structured Approach* by Velleman would be good choices. Another good book would be *An Introduction to Mathematical Reasoning* by Eccles.

I might also recommend *Concrete Mathematics: A Foundation for Computer Science* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik. This book has been at Stanford for many years as the text for their mathematical foundations for CS course and is quite popular these days.

Comment: Also, just to put it out there: I learned from _Discrete and Combinatorial Mathematics: An Applied Introduction, Fifth Edition_ by Grimaldi. This is an okay book, but I'm not sure I would recommend it.